# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed even after closing cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, memory, memory-leaks, android-cursor

There are many questions on SO about CursorWindowAllocatoinException:

- [SQLite Android Database Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340257/sqlite-android-database-cursor-window-allocation-of-2048-kb-failed)
- [Could not allocate CursorWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495713/could-not-allocate-cursorwindow)
- [Out of Memory when allocating cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577400/out-of-memory-when-allocating-cursors)
- [Android SQLite CursorWindowAllocationException crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029437/android-mysqlite-cursorwindowallocationexception-crash)

All of them suggest that cursor must be closed after use. But that did not resolve my problem. Here is my code:

```
String query = "select serial from tbl1 union select serial from tbl2 union select serial from tbl3";
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        SettingsDatabaseHelper dal = new SettingsDatabaseHelper(
                c);
        db = dal.getReadableDatabase();
        cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int numRows = cur.getCount();
        if (numRows > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            int serialIdx = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("serial");
            for (boolean hasItem = cur.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = cur
                    .moveToNext()) {

                String serial = cur.getString(serialIdx);
                if (Validator.getInstance().isValidSerial(serial))
                    serials.add(serial);

            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();

        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }
```

I run this method every few seconds. After half an hour, I get `CursorWindowAllocationException`  in `int numRows=cur.getCount();` and then my service stops.

Since I am closing the cursor, there may be a problem with my Helper class. Here is the code:

```
public class SettingsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private static final String TBL_CREATE="create table...";



    public SettingsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(TBL_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this exception from being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was querying the database from a service. When I did it from an activity, the problem never occurred again.

Alongside querying, I was reading from the serial port within the same service. Maybe that caused the problem. However, when I used an activity instead of the service, the problem never happened again.

Comment: I didnt get answer. I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in my application while loading more than 500 songs from android  media store.

closing the cursor will not solve your problem.

you should use [AsyncTask.](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Uvw-gfmSwYE).
inside doInBackground method write the code for retrieving values from cursor.

public class CursorLoader extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String query = "select serial from tbl1 union select serial from tbl2 union select serial from tbl3";
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
Cursor cur = null;
try {
    SettingsDatabaseHelper dal = new SettingsDatabaseHelper(
            c);
    db = dal.getReadableDatabase();
    cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int numRows = cur.getCount();
    if (numRows > 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();

        int serialIdx = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("serial");
        for (boolean hasItem = cur.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = cur
                .moveToNext()) {

            String serial = cur.getString(serialIdx);
            if (Validator.getInstance().isValidSerial(serial))
                serials.add(serial);

        }
    }
} finally {
    if (cur != null)
        cur.close();

    if (db != null)
        db.close();
}

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, while i am calling the DATA BASE, in the service class using forever loop.

My code was like:

```
service ()
 {
void run()
   {
     while(conditionisTrue)
       {
              db.getRecord();  //I remove this code from here and put it in the start of service c
        }
    }
 }
```